# When changing domains, should Google Search Console change of address also be used for domains that redirect to the main domain?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-results, change-address-tool

I have site A redirect 301 to site B, now I have site C and want to redirect B to it, what is the best way to change of address with google search console?

Should I set only change of address B to C? or set change of address A to C also? (with current redirect 301 status A to B, B to C)